# Iterating over user input

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script similar to this:

```
echo Enter a sentence
read line
for $x in $line ; do
echo $x
done
```

However, it only echos the entire input and not each word in the input as intended. Why is that? And is there a way to get around that while not knowing the number of words to be entered, using a for loop, and preferably not using the read -a option, because I know how to make that work but I don't believe it meets the requirements that've been imposed.

Thanks
OSFTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for x in $(echo "$line")
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea why this worked, but you shouldn't have the `$` in your for header and it should work as expected, assuming your `IFS` is correct

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter a sentence
read line
IFS=$' \t\n' #reset to default IFS
for x in $line ; do
  echo "$x"
done
```

e.g.

```
> ./script 
Enter a sentence
a b c d
a
b
c
d
```